# Probability first event of one Poisson process occurs before first event of a second and independent Poisson process

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

**Question:**
Assume $N_1(t)$ and $N_1(t)$ are two independent Poisson processes with rates
$λ_1$ and $λ_2$, respectively. Show that $N_1(t)$ + $N_2(t)$ is a Poisson Process with rate $λ_1 + λ_2$, and use this to obtain the probability that the first event of the combined process is from the $N_2$ process.

**Where I'm stuck:**
I've shown that $N_1(t)$ + $N_2(t)$ is a Poisson Process with rate $λ_1 + λ_2$. The problem is that when I use this to obtain the probability that the first event of the combined process is from the $N_2$ process, I get a result that differs from what I get when I compute the same probability in a different manner. In particular:

I reason that the first event of the combined process will be from the $N_2$ process if and only if $T^{1+2}_1$, the time of the first event of the combined process, is less than $T^{1}_1$, the time of the first event of the $N_1$ process.
Since $N_1(t) + N_2(t)$ is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$,  $T^{1+2}_1$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$. And since $N_1(t)$ is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda_1$, $T^{1}_1$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda_1$.
Therefore:
$$P(\textrm{1st event of } N_1(t) + N_2(t) \textrm{ is from } N_2(t)) = P(T^{1+2}_1 < T^{1}_1) = \frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2) + \lambda_1}$$

However, as a check I also reasoned that the first event of the combined process will be from the $N_2$  process if and only if $T^2_1$, the time of the first event of the $N_2$ process, which is exponential with rate $\lambda_2$, is less than $T^1_1$, the time of the first event of the $N_1$ process, which is exponential with rate $\lambda_1$. Therefore:
$$P(\textrm{1st event of } N_1(t) + N_2(t) \textrm{ is from } N_2(t)) = P(T^{2}_1 < T^{1}_1) = \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$$
And these two results differ.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The correct answer is $\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$. It is true that the superposition of the two Poisson processes is a Poisson process with rate equal to the sum of the rates of the two, but this isn't relevant to the probability in question, as we can simply consider the two processes individually.

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks. But the question I'm trying to solve specifically asks me to use the superposition to calculate the probability. So I was more concerned about where my reasoning was off in that attempt.

Comment: The superposed process has time until next arrival of $\bar{X}= \frac{1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$ and the underlying 2nd process has a time averaged renewal rate of $\lambda_2$, which implies (w/ reward of 1 for each arrival in process 2) that $E[R_1] = \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$.  A more basic way -- consider each process as limits of independent shrinking Bernouli process, where probability of a 'collision' is negligibly small.  Given an arrival in the merged process at time t, the probability it is from process 2 must be $\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2} + \epsilon(t)$

Comment: typo note:  the above $\epsilon$ isn't actually a function of time $t$ but is a function of how many times the Bernouli process has been shrunk... and $\epsilon \to 0$ as you take a limit and recover a poisson process.  There's a simple direct derivation in Blitzstein and Hwangs free book in the short poisson process chapter https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/stat110/home