# An event from first poisson process occurs before an event from another independent poisson process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

This question is related to this [question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567333/probability-first-event-of-one-poisson-process-occurs-before-first-event-of-a-se) I'm struggling to get the correct answer from an approach I follow and it doesn't look wrong to me.

The question is simply if we have two independent Poisson processes: $N_1(t)$ and $N_2(t)$ with different rates $\lambda_1 , \lambda_2$ consequently. Find the probability that a first arrival comes from $N2$ before the first arrival of $N1$.

So, if the first event occurs from $N_2(t)$ Poisson process before the first event occurs from $N_1(t)$, which is also a Poisson process. Then simply we start with

$$P(N_2(t) = 1 , N_1(t) = 0) = P(N_2(t) = 1) * P(N_1(t) = 0)$$

Where $t$ is just an arbitrary time interval. However, this doesn't lead to the expected answer which is $\lambda_2/(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$. I think there is a flaw and misunderstanding in my approach but I am not able to see what is wrong in my way of thinking?

Comment: Your fornula is missing an existential quantifier. The first event in $N_2$ occurs before the first event in $N_1$ not when $N_2(t)=1,N_1(t)=0$ obtains at some time $t$ (I'm not sure what you mean by referring to that time as "just an arbitrary time interval") but if there exists a time at which it obtains. So if you wanted to pursue this approach, you'd have to figure out the probability for this existence statement to hold. That seems pretty difficult, but as you probably know, there are much simpler ways to get the result.

Comment: @joriki $t$ here means a time interval $[0,t]$. What I'm trying to say is that what is the probability that an event occurs in the time interval $[0,t]$ for $N2$ and no event occurs in the time interval $[0,t]$ for $N1$. I think it is equivalent to say that the an $N2$ arrival happen before $N1$ for this specific interval. Haven't really caught on what you refer to as "existence statement"?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification).

Comment: @joriki I understand that but existential quantifier for what I mean?

Comment: For the time (or time interval, as you prefer) $t$.